# To display the only column in a table whose value starts with a single letter

Tags: mysql, database

I have to display `first_Name` of clients Table (clients) starting from `M` only what can I do.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE first_Name like "%M"
```

It doesn't show, why?

Answer (score 0):

change the wildchar position to the end 'M%'  and let M firts

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE first_Name like "M%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from clients where first_Name like "M%"
```